# aapt finished with non-zero exit value 126

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, gradle, aapt

I am using gradle to setup my android project. And I get this error when I transfer my project to a Linux machine, not sure what is missing. Anyone can help me? 
the full error as below:

```
Process 'command '/root/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt'' finished with exit value 126 (state: FAILED)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/root/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 126
```

I've seen a lot exit value 1, 2 or 127, but this is the first time I get 126, no idea what happened, my OS is:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 10 17:27:01 UTC 2016
```

and the build version in my project is:

```
compileSdkVersion=26
buildToolsVersion=26.0.2
minSdkVersion=16
targetSdkVersion=22
versionCode=1
version=1.7.4
```

I don't wanna change the buildToolsVersion in project because of some reason, and the project itself works fine in other machine, so I am thinking about I missed something in this Linux device.
It is the first time I trying to configure Android environment in Linux device. 
Thanks in advance for your help, any idea is also welcome to share.